# cookiecutter-django template django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-celery, cookiecutter-django

I generated a django app using the cookiecutter template and got an error that `celery_beat_periodictask` does not exist.

I ran the following docker-compose command:
`docker-compose -f local.yml up -d --build` 
Checked the logs for individual services (services in the docker-compose file)**your text** using:
`docker-compose -f local.yml logs`

I got the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 723, in execute
local_celerybeat             |     raise ex.with_traceback(None)
local_celerybeat             | [2023-07-26 11:46:23,580: WARNING/SpawnProcess-1] django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist
local_celerybeat             | LINE 1: ...ango_celery_beat_periodictask"."description" FROM "django_ce
```

I decided to add the dynamically generated docker IP address to the settings.local file and this error disappears. Is there anyway to fix this issue before running the docker-compose command?